# Problema con recursion

Tags: c++, dev-c++, c++11

Este es mi codigo:

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void controlNatal(int N, int H, int C1, int C2, int M, int T){

int adultas=N;
int nacen=H;
int crecen=C1;
int maduran=C2;
int aceptan;

adultas = N + maduran;

if(adultas <= M){
    aceptan = adultas;
}else{
    aceptan = M;
}

if(T > 0){
    controlNatal(adultas,aceptan,nacen,crecen,M,T-1);
}else{
    cout<<adultas;
}
}

int main(){

int adultas,huevos,maxHuevos,anios;
int crecen = 0, maduran = 0;

cin>>adultas>>huevos>>maxHuevos>>anios;

controlNatal(adultas,huevos,crecen,maduran,maxHuevos,anios);

}
```

El problema que tengo es que en la parte del resultado, tiene que salir 22 pero me sale 24, no se que es lo que tengo mal. Intente incializar la variable huevos en el main con 0, y hay si da el resulatdo deseado, pero cuando coloco otro numero en la parte de entra de la imagen como por ejemplo : 4 2 6 6.

El resultado me sale 22 pero no tiene que ser ese.

Este es un ejemplo de como debe de salir el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso son 4 adultas, 1 es un huevo por adulto, 6 es el numero de huevos maximos que se aceptan y el ultimo numero que es 6 es el numero de años que van a transcurrir.

Comment: ¿No tienes una descripción del problema donde diga cuando se aceptan, cuando se rechazan, que es 4 1 6 6? ¿Cuál es la condición de parada? Edita tu pregunta y agrega esa información si la tienes.

Comment: Ya lo edite, no se si asi sea un poco mas claro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La idea es crear una función que, además de los parámetros que se pasan, lleve conteo de los `huevos`, de los `nacidos` y de los `bebes`. Cada año que pasa, los `huevos` pasan a ser `bebes`, los `bebes` pasan a ser `nacidos`, los `nacidos` pasan a ser `adultos` y se crean la cantidad de huevos por adulto que haya.

Puedes ejecutarlo y testear el programa online [acá](https://onlinegdb.com/ie053eO6Wz):

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int controlNatal (int adultas, int huevosPorAdulta, int maxNoHuevos, int anios, int huevos = 0, int nacidos = 0, int bebes = 0)
{

  if (anios <= 0)
  {
      return adultas;
  }

  int huevosPuestos = adultas * huevosPorAdulta;
  if (huevosPuestos > maxNoHuevos)
  {
      huevosPuestos = maxNoHuevos;
  }

  adultas = adultas + nacidos;
  nacidos = huevos;
  bebes = nacidos;
  huevos = huevosPuestos;

  return controlNatal(adultas, huevosPorAdulta, maxNoHuevos, anios - 1,huevos, nacidos, bebes);
}

int main ()
{

  int adultas, huevos, maxHuevos, anios;

  cin >> adultas >> huevos >> maxHuevos >> anios;

  cout << controlNatal (adultas, huevos, maxHuevos, anios);
}
```

Te adjunto también una solución usando `javascript` y que puedes ejecutar desde acá. Esto te ilustra que el algoritmo del problema es simplemente exportable a otros lenguajes:

```js
function controlNatal(adultas, huevosPorAdulta, maxNoHuevos, anios, huevos = 0, nacidos = 0, bebes = 0){
    if(anios <= 0){
        return adultas;
    }

    let huevosPuestos = adultas * huevosPorAdulta;
    if(huevosPuestos > maxNoHuevos) {
        huevosPuestos = maxNoHuevos
    } 

    adultas = adultas + nacidos;
    nacidos = huevos;
    bebes = nacidos;
    huevos = huevosPuestos; 

    return controlNatal(adultas, huevosPorAdulta, maxNoHuevos, anios - 1, huevos, bebes);    
}

console.log(controlNatal(4, 1, 6, 6));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvio bastante. Solo una pregunta, por que huevos, nacidos y bebes los inicialisaste en 0 desde un principio?.

Comment: ¿Cómo que por qué? Porque al inicio no hay ni nacidos, ni bebes. Y no son parámetros que por las indicaciones que adjuntas, reciba la función. L a función debe poder llamarse con 4 parámetros solamente.